# How to pass Django variables in Angular 7 app

Tags: django, angular, python-2.7, angular7

In the current project based on Angularjs 1.6.9, I am passing django constant values through the main html page using 'angular.constant' as shown below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  angular
      .module("myDashboardApp")
      .constant('backendData', {
        staticUrl: "{% static '' %}",
        user_id: "{{ user_id }}"
      });
</script>
```

Now I am rewriting the entire app in Angular 7. How can I pass these values so that it is accessible in all the angular7 components?

I create 'backendData' (key-value pairs) on front end where I set its values through context data sent by django view

PS. This is my first project in Angular7 so I am not sure how to access Django values in typescript file.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can store Django variable in window object:

```html
<script>
  window['backendData'] = {
    staticUrl: "{% static '' %}",
    user_id: "{{ user_id }}"
  };
</script>
```

And access them in typescript file(s) via window: `window['backendData']['user_id']`